# Spring Data: Saving LocalTime to MongoDB using CustomConversions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

How do I only convert the string in HH:mm format to LocalTime and the other way?

Here is my mongo config and right now it is converting any fields that are of String type to LocalTime and failed in the process because some of them are not meant to be LocalTime...  but some of them are LocalTime in String format, so those actually need to get converted to LocalTime

```
@Bean
public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(NoOpDbRefResolver.INSTANCE, this.mongoMappingContext());
    converter.setCustomConversions(this.customConversions());
    converter.afterPropertiesSet();
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext() {
    MongoMappingContext context = new MongoMappingContext();
    context.setSimpleTypeHolder(new SimpleTypeHolder(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            LocalTime.class
    )), MongoSimpleTypes.HOLDER));
    return context;
}

@Bean
public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(new LocalTimeToStringConverter());
    converters.add(new StringToLocalTimeConverter());
    return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
}
```